# Use "link" and "post_url" with variables

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I would like to manipulate the "post_url" tag of Liquid/Jekyll with some variables. These are the two things I would like to do :

**Store result into variable**

I would like to store the result of post_url in a variable, currently, this does not work :

```
{%- assign _page_url = post_url 2019-05-19-test -%}
```

_page_url is empty after this line. :(

**Use variable as an argument**

But the main issue occurs when I try to use a variable as an argument. _item.post is a variable which contains a string pointing to a correct post.

```
{%- post_url _item.post -%}
```

Throw the exception :

> Liquid Exception: Could not parse name of post "_item.post" in tag
>   'post_url'. Make sure the post exists and the name is correct.
>
> Jekyll::Errors::InvalidPostNameError: '_item.post' does not contain
>   valid date and/or title. in /_layouts/page.html
>                Error: Could not parse name of post "_item.post" in tag 'post_url'. Make sure the post exists and the name is correct.
>   Jekyll::Errors::InvalidPostNameError: '_item.post' does not contain
>   valid date and/or title.
>                Error: Run jekyll build --trace for more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `post_url` is a Liquid tag, you need to include it in a way that's executing that tag's logic first so it can store the result. In these cases, you can use `{% capture %}` instead of `{% assign %}`:

```
{%- capture _page_url -%}
  {% post_url 2019-05-19-test %}
{%- endcapture -%}
```

As for using variables as an argument to `post_url`, this is not currently possible with this tag. Looking at the [tag's code](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/tags/post_url.rb#L11), it takes everything after `post_url` in the tag literally and attempts to parse it using their defined structure for posts, whereas something like the [`include` tag](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/tags/include.rb#L91) has an actual step to detect variables and resolve their value. However, it looks like it will be possible in Jekyll 4.0 ([see this PR](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/7582)). You may be able to get this behavior now by using the [pre-alpha version](https://rubygems.org/gems/jekyll/versions/4.0.0.pre.alpha1), though it's not stable so you may see unexpected behavior elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Now that Jekyll 4.0 is out, you can use variables using `{{}}` inside the `{% %}` markup:

```
{%- post_url {{ _item.post }} -%}
```